# Get password authentication failed after update Laravel to version 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Previously I had a Laravel app with Laravel 5.7, and now I updated my app to newest Laravel 9 version. But I get an error with my pgsql connection password, even though my .env it's still same.

I try to connect with pgadmin, dbeaver and it's working, only in laravel that get an error.

I already run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` but the problem still remain.

.env part

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=159.x.x.x
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=infinite-mob
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

laravel.log

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user \"user\"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user \"user\" at /var/www/app.ics-seafood.com/app_laravel9/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
```

Comment: did you run php artisan optimize:clear, installed all composer dependencies? Please show the exact error log.

Comment: I already run composer update and install, and optimize:clear is not fixing the error. updated the question for error log

Comment: Are you sure your user and password are correct?

Comment: I'm sure enough my username and password is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its turn out my password is a complex password, like

> S3cur1ti%$#@!

so adding `""` in DB_PASSWORD .env solved the problem

like this

> DB_PASSWORD="S3cur1ti%$#@!"